# Horizontal line filling the space between TextView and parent

Tags: android, layout

Basically I would like to get an effect like this shown in the picture. The horizontal line on both sides of a TextView. How can I do this?

[image]

Comment: Are you Do this using XML OR PROGRAMATICALLY, i mean You have only two header and text?

Comment: @Samir Just xml - it's not editable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Its Easy Like : :**

```
  <View
        android:id="@+id/hline1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="5dip"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="#000000" />
```

**Your XML Layout is Like : :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFF0"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <View
        android:id="@+id/hline1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="5dip"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/header1"
        android:background="#000000" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/header1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="   Header   "
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/hline2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="5dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/header1"
        android:background="#000000" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/header1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="Some Text Goes to here..........................."
        android:textColor="#000000" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a simple shape drawable and set that as the left/right drawables on the TextView.  The TextView width has to be Fill_Parent.